# How to refer My own custom attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Please describe how to refer tag using my custom attribute using jQuery.

I have tag like this :

```
<a user="kasun" href="#" id="id1">Show More...</a>
```

I want to refer tag without refering id. like

```
 $('#id1')
```

I want to refer it like:

```
$('#user')//this is wrong. I mentioned this code only for understand what I mean.
```

Thank You.

Comment: 1) use data-user and access using $("#id1").data("user") or 2) use $("#id1").prop("user")

Comment: You should be making use of `data`, like @mplungjan suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('[user]')
```

or

```
$('[user="kasun"]')
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P2jv3/)

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Amiros answer. I would like to give one more option to select those elements which are having custom attribute in ONLY anchor tags.

$("a[user]")

$("a[user='kasun']")